# Invoking Web Request in PowerShell Version 2.0 Timed out

Tags: powershell

This in continuation to one of my previous queries [Invoke-WebRequest equivalent in PowerShell v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120703/invoke-webrequest-equivalent-in-powershell-v2)

Im trying to run the below script, it ran 2-3 timed but after that im repeatedly getting the below timed out error

Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"

[image: Request Timed Out Error]

Here's the script

```
function Invoke_Workflow {

        param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$arg,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$whostname,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$uuid,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$wfname,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$wpassword,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$wusername

        )


$body = 
"<wInput>
  <userInputValues>
   <userInputEntry value='$arg' key='stringArgument'/>
  </userInputValues>
  <executionDateAndTime></executionDateAndTime>
  <comments></comments> 
</wInput>"

# Disable certificate validation using certificate policy that ignores all certificates
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    public class IDontCarePolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public IDontCarePolicy() {}
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint sPoint, X509Certificate cert,
            WebRequest wRequest, int certProb) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = new-object IDontCarePolicy 


$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $wfapassword -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($wfausername, $password)

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URI1)
$request.ContentType = "application/xml"
$request.Method = "POST"
$request.Credentials = $credential

# $request | Get-Member  for a list of methods and properties 

try
{

$request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;
$request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
    $requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream()
    $streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($requestStream)
    $streamWriter.Write($body)
}

finally
{
    if ($null -ne $streamWriter) { $streamWriter.Dispose() }
    if ($null -ne $requestStream) { $requestStream.Dispose() }
}

$res = $request.GetResponse()

$request.Abort()


}
```

Comment: So...what's the question? How to increase the timeout limit? How to handle the timeout condition? How to fix the remote service so that it doesn't timeout? Other? Also, please post your error messages as **text** so that they're readable (and searchable). My eyes aren't so good anymore and I can barely read that screenshot. More importantly, no search engine can read it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is most likely related to the default Servicepoint connection limit which is 2.

You can increase it (10 as an example below) and if you are making many requests in a single powershell session then adding a check of the currentconnection count and clearing them (8 as an example below) prior to reaching the set connection limit:

```
$request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit =10;
$conn=$request.ServicePoint.CurrentConnections
    If ($conn -ge 8) {
    $request.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("")
}
```